# Why does double.NAN exist but num.NAN and int.NAN don't, in Google's Dart programming language?

Tags: dart

Why does `double.NAN` exist but `num.NAN` and `int.NAN` don't, in Google's Dart programming language?

Comment: NaN isn't a concept for integers (well, it could be, but no-one implements it that way)...

Answer (score 7):

NaN is a specific double value that is specified in the IEEE standard for floating-point values (IEEE 754).

NaN has special properties (like NaN != NaN), and those properties are implemented by the CPU.

Integers do not have any explicit NaN value.

Comment: You cannot use IEEE 754 specification to explain something about num, int and double in Dart. Javascript uses this standard, true. Yet Dart has its own way to handle numbers : just to quote one -huge- difference, integers of arbitrary precision are possible in Dart, when they cannot be handled with IEEE754.

Comment: IEEE 754 is the "IEEE Standard for Floating-Point Arithmetic", and Dart's floating-point numbers (as do all CPUs) follows this standard. IEEE 754 contains the specification for NaN, and is therefore the right answer for questions about NaN. Integers (a feature glaringly missing in JavaScript) are not specified in IEEE 754. Most languages usually use IEEE 754 for floating-point values, and integers (fixed size or not) for integers. I don't know of any language that has a NaN value for integers, since this is a IEEE 754 feature.

Comment: A = A ==> A = A. So A = A.

Comment: I guess the point is that the existence of the IEEE754 standard doesn't prohibit the existence of a NaN concept for integers.  It's just that no-one implements NaN for integers.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth IEEE 754 is a technical standard for floating-point computation. It not describes the integer number computation. In this case it doesn't prohibit the existence of a NaN concept for integers. In computer science, an integer is a datum of integral data type, a data type which represents some finite subset of the mathematical integers. Mathematical set of integers is a subset of the real numbers, and consists of the natural numbers (1, 2, 3, ...), zero (0) and the negatives of the natural numbers (−1, −2, −3, ...).

Comment: ieee 754 -- a standard for floating point -- is a total red herring here. int is a class in dart. NaN does not exist simply because it has not been implemented. You might be able to do so using extension methods.